# How to convert below method to Java 8 inline function?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I need to convert below method java 8 inline function. need some expert help and explanation to do this.

```
@Override
public boolean a(final Collection<DoseDetailMutableDTO> detailModels) {
    for (DoseDetailMutableDTO dd : detailModels) {
         final boolean doseDetailTextScheduled = isDoseDetailTextScheduled(dd, 1);
         if (doseDetailTextScheduled) {
             return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and Are there any short cut to do this intelj IDE ?

Comment: Intellij Gives more java 8 feature than any other IDE . Just do `ctrl space`. Even it will change your traditional loop to lambda try `RightClick ->Analyse->Inspect code`

Comment: @manfromnowhere Are there any comparisions of what an ide can or cannot do regarding java 8 features? I am very interested of where this statement ("Intellij Gives more java 8 feature than any other IDE") comes from.

Comment: Please refer to the article [Migrating to Java 8](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrating-to-java-8.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of [`Stream.anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) as:

```
public boolean a(final Collection<DoseDetailMutableDTO> detailModels) {
    return detailModels.stream()
                       .anyMatch(dd -> isDoseDetailTextScheduled(dd, 1));
}
```

> returns `true` if any elements of the stream match the provided predicate, otherwise `false`

***Edit***: (from comments)

> The control to learn for such suggested shortcuts on IntelliJ IDEA is
>   `Ctrl+Space` or on MacOS can use `Alt+Enter` as well.

Comment: The control to learn for such suggested shortcuts on IntelliJIDEA is `Ctrl+Space` or on MacOS can use `Alt+Enter` as well.

Comment: This comment can go along with the answer IMO

Comment: The problem here is you assume isDoseDetailTextScheduled having no side effects. To get the same work order of "for" you need to use Tim Biegeleisens - solution. Same applies to parallel execution of the stream.

Answer (score 5):

We can try using a stream here:

```
@Override
public boolean a (final Collection<DoseDetailMutableDTO> detailModels) {
    return detailModels.stream()
               .filter(x -> isDoseDetailTextScheduled(x, 1))
               .findFirst()
               .orElse(false);
}
```

Actually, to make your method `null` safe, in the event that the input list might be `null`, we can try this:

```
@Override
public boolean a (final Collection<DoseDetailMutableDTO> detailModels) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(detailModels)
                   .map(Collection::stream)
                   .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
                   .filter(x -> isDoseDetailTextScheduled(x, 1))
                   .findFirst()
                   .orElse(false);
}
```

Comment: you could simplify the first example to `.findFirst().isPresent()` and the second example to `return detailModels != null && detailModels.stream().filter(x -> isDoseDetailTextScheduled(x, 1))
                   .findFirst().isPresent();`. creating an Optional only to check whether something is null or not should be avoided as it's more memory hungry and contradicts the main purpose of Optional.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `anyMatch` for this.
Since the second parameter to the function is constant you can write a method that calls `isDoseDetailTextScheduled`. 
I think it becomes even more concise:

```
public boolean a(final Collection<DoseDetailMutableDTO> detailModels) {
   return detailModels.stream().anyMatch(this::isDoseDetailTextScheduledOne);
}

public boolean isDoseDetailTextScheduledOne(DoseDetailMutableDTO dto) {
    return isDoseDetailTextScheduled(dto, 1);
}
```